# Creating SQL pivot where duplicate column names exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a couple of tables (in a SQL Server 2014 SP2 database) on which I am trying to pivot and I am trying to re-name some of the columns from one of those tables.

The tables looks like this:

**dataSourceSnapshot**

```
|   snapshotId |     snapshotTime |
-----------------------------------
|            1 | 2021-12-01 07:00 |
|            2 | 2021-12-02 07:00 |
...
```

**datasource**

```
| snapshotId | dsRecordId | dsId | dsName |       dsTableDate |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |          1 |    1 |    cpu |  2021-12-01 07:00 |
|          1 |          2 |    2 |    mem |  2021-12-01 07:00 |
|          1 |          3 |    3 |  cache |  2021-12-01 07:00 |
|          2 |          4 |    1 |    cpu |  2021-12-01 07:00 |
|          2 |          5 |    2 |    mem |  2021-12-01 07:00 |
|          2 |          6 |    3 |  cache |  2021-12-01 07:00 |
...
```

**datasourceProperty**

This is a truncated list of datasource properties.

```
| dsRecordId | dsPropPropertyRecordId | dsPropPropertyName | dsPropPropertyValue |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |                      1 |                 id |                   1 |  
|          1 |                      2 |        description |           cpu stats |
|          1 |                      3 |               name |                 cpu |
|          1 |                      4 |    collectInterval |                 300 |
|          1 |                      5 |              group |                     |
|          1 |                      6 |         dataPoints |     System.Object[] |
|          2 |                      7 |                 id |                   2 |  
|          2 |                      8 |        description |        memory stats |
|          2 |                      9 |               name |                 mem |
|          2 |                     10 |    collectInterval |                 300 |
|          2 |                     11 |              group |                     |
|          2 |                     12 |         dataPoints |     System.Object[] |
|          3 |                     13 |                 id |                   3 |  
|          3 |                     14 |        description |                     |
|          3 |                     15 |               name |               cache |
|          3 |                     16 |    collectInterval |                 600 |
|          3 |                     17 |              group |                     |
|          3 |                     18 |         dataPoints |     System.Object[] |
...
```

**datapointProperty**

This is a truncated list of datapoint properties.

```
| dsRecordId | dpRecordId | dpPropertyName |    dpPropertyValue |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |          1 |             id |                  1 |  
|          1 |          2 |   datasourceId |                  1 |
|          1 |          3 |           name |           cpuState |
|          1 |          4 |    description |                    |
|          1 |          5 |      alertExpr |             != 0 0 |
|          1 |          6 |           type |                  2 |
|          1 |          7 |             id |                  2 |  
|          1 |          8 |   datasourceId |                  1 |
|          1 |          9 |           name |        freePercent |
|          1 |         10 |    description |                    |
|          1 |         11 |      alertExpr |           >= 90 90 |
|          1 |         12 |           type |                  2 |
|          2 |         13 |             id |                  3 |
|          2 |         14 |   datasourceId |                  2 |
|          2 |         15 |           name |        freePercent |
|          2 |         16 |    description | Memory utilization |
|          2 |         17 |      alertExpr |           >= 90 90 |
|          2 |         18 |           type |                  2 |
|          3 |         19 |             id |                  4 |
|          3 |         20 |   datasourceId |                  3 |
|          3 |         21 |           name |              state |
|          3 |         22 |    description |                    |
|          3 |         23 |      alertExpr |            = 1 1 1 |
|          3 |         24 |           type |                  4 |
...
```

I am trying to get a row per datasource (but only the most recent instance of that datasource's entry) and per datapoint, which includes all of the datasource properties, with the datapoint properties pivoted so that they are columns. Something like this:

```
| dsRecordId | id |    description |    name | collectInterval | group |      dataPoints | dp_id | dp_datasourceId |     dp_name |     dp_description | dp_alertExpr | dp_type |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |  1 |      cpu stats |     cpu |             300 |       | System.Object[] |     1 |               1 |    cpuState |                    |       != 0 0 |       2 |
|          1 |  1 |      cpu stats |     cpu |             300 |       | System.Object[] |     2 |               1 | freePercent |                    |     >= 90 90 |       2 |
|          2 |  2 |   memory stats |     mem |             300 |       | System.Object[] |     3 |               2 | freePercent | Memory utilization |     >= 90 90 |       2 |
|          3 |  3 |                |   cache |             600 |       | System.Object[] |     4 |               3 |       state |                    |      = 1 1 1 |       4 |
```

I have a bit of T-SQL that will pivot, but because datasources and datapoints both have id, name, and description properties, I have to exclude those properties in the pivot. This query:

```
DECLARE 
    @dsPropPropertyColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @dpPropertyColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

-- select the property names
--- properties in the datasourceProperty table
SELECT @dsPropPropertyColumns = (
    SELECT DISTINCT '[' + [dsPropPropertyName] + ']' + ','
    FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot dss
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasource ds ON ds.snapshotId = dss.snapshotId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasourceProperty dsp ON dsp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
    WHERE dss.snapshotTime = (
        SELECT MAX(snapshotTime) FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot
    )
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')

--- properties in the datapointProperty table
SELECT @dpPropertyColumns = (
    SELECT DISTINCT '[' + [dpPropertyName] + ']' + ','
    FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot dss
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasource ds ON ds.snapshotId = dss.snapshotId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datapointProperty dp ON dp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
    WHERE dss.snapshotTime = (
        SELECT MAX(snapshotTime) FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot
    )
    AND [dpPropertyName] NOT IN ('name','id', 'description')
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')

-- remove the trailing comma
SET @dsPropPropertyColumns = LEFT(@dsPropPropertyColumns, LEN(@dsPropPropertyColumns) - 1);
SET @dpPropertyColumns = LEFT(@dpPropertyColumns, LEN(@dpPropertyColumns) - 1);

-- construct dynamic SQL
SET @sql ='
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT dsp.dsRecordId, dsp.dsPropPropertyName, dsp.dsPropPropertyValue, dp.dpPropertyName, dp.dpPropertyValue
    FROM dbo.snapshot dss
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasource ds ON ds.snapshotId = dss.snapshotId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasourceProperty dsp ON dsp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datapointProperty dp ON dp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
    WHERE dss.snapshotTime = (
        SELECT MAX(snapshotTime) FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot
    )
) t1
PIVOT (
    MAX(dsPropPropertyValue) FOR dsPropPropertyName IN ('+ @dsPropPropertyColumns +')
) AS pivot_table
PIVOT (
    MAX(dpPropertyValue) FOR dpPropertyName IN ('+ @dpPropertyColumns +')
) AS pivot_table2
ORDER BY id
'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Produces this output:

```
| dsRecordId | id |    description |    name | collectInterval | group |      dataPoints | datasourceId | alertExpr | type |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |  1 |      cpu stats |     cpu |             300 |       | System.Object[] |            1 |    != 0 0 |    2 |
|          1 |  1 |      cpu stats |     cpu |             300 |       | System.Object[] |            1 |  >= 90 90 |    2 |
|          2 |  2 |   memory stats |     mem |             300 |       | System.Object[] |            2 |  >= 90 90 |    2 |
|          3 |  3 |                |   cache |             600 |       | System.Object[] |            3 |   = 1 1 1 |    4 |
```

I have `Select *...` on line 38 because I do not know all of the property names. While I am writing this, it occurs to me that, maybe I can use the column name variables (@dsPropPropertyColumns and @dpPropertyColumns) there somehow? What would that look like?

I looked at the following questions, but I do not think they answer my issue:

- [Dynamic SQL Pivot Causing Duplicate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183434/dynamic-sql-pivot-causing-duplicate-columns)
- [SQL Server Dynamic
  Pivot Table - Column Name Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184631/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-table-column-name-duplicate)

The question is: How can I dynamically generate the column list for pivoting, and prepend "dp_" to each column name from the datasourceProperty table, so I can include the id; name; and description columns without getting a "duplicate column name" error? I think that will result in the desired output.

Comment: I do not understand how that helps, can you be more specific? I can generate the list properties using your suggestion, but I still end up with two "id" columns: `SELECT '[' + [dsPropPropertyName] + ']' + ','
FROM dbo.snapshot dss
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasource ds ON ds.snapshotId = dss.snapshotId
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasourceProperty dsp ON dsp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
WHERE dss.snapshotTime = (
 SELECT MAX(dataSourceSnapshotTime) FROM logicmonitor.dataSourceSnapshot
)
GROUP BY [dsPropPropertyName]`

Comment: `SELECT @dpPropertyColumns = ( SELECT DISTINCT quotename(concat('dp_',[dpPropertyName])) ...`  

`SET @sql ='SELECT * FROM (...dsp.dsPropPropertyValue, concat('dp_', dp.dpPropertyName) as dpPropertyName, dp.dpPropertyValue ...`

Comment: @lptr, I made the changes and now I have the "dp_" columns, which is great. What I do not have, is a row for each datapoint. I thought that would happen with the pivots, since there are multiple instances.

Comment: If there are multiple instances of a datapoint per dsRecordId, assign a ‘grouping number’ to the datapoints `SET @sql ='SELECT * FROM (...row_number() over(partition by dp.dsRecordId, dp.dpPropertyName order by dp.dpRecordId) as datapointrn,...`

Comment: That did not produce what I expected. To help with clarity (and to incorporate the quotename/concat) I created [Output multiple rows after joining and pivoting multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70523711/output-multiple-rows-after-joining-and-pivoting-multiple-tables). I will mark this one answered.

Comment: you have used row_number() for dpPropertyName…row_number() should be added as an additional identifier to separate duplicate propertynames from each other..`row_number() as order by dp.dpRecordId) as datapointrn` <- it is datapointrn... dpProperty name should be concat( dp, …) as in the first comment

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response from @lptr, I updated the T-SQL to:

```
DECLARE 
    @dsPropPropertyColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @dpPropertyColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

-- select the property names
--- properties in the datasourceProperty table
SELECT @dsPropPropertyColumns = (
    SELECT DISTINCT '[' + [dsPropPropertyName] + ']' + ','
    FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot dss
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasource ds ON ds.snapshotId = dss.snapshotId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasourceProperty dsp ON dsp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
    WHERE dss.snapshotTime = (
        SELECT MAX(snapshotTime) FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot
    )
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')

--- properties in the datapointProperty table
SELECT @dpPropertyColumns = (
    SELECT DISTINCT '[' + [dpPropertyName] + ']' + ','
    FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot dss
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasource ds ON ds.snapshotId = dss.snapshotId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datapointProperty dp ON dp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
    WHERE dss.snapshotTime = (
        SELECT MAX(snapshotTime) FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot
    )
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')

-- remove the trailing comma
SET @dsPropPropertyColumns = LEFT(@dsPropPropertyColumns, LEN(@dsPropPropertyColumns) - 1);
SET @dpPropertyColumns = LEFT(@dpPropertyColumns, LEN(@dpPropertyColumns) - 1);

-- construct dynamic SQL
SET @sql ='
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT dsp.dsRecordId, dsp.dsPropPropertyName, dsp.dsPropPropertyValue, CONCAT(''dp_'', dp.dpPropertyName) as dpPropertyName, dp.dpPropertyValue
    FROM dbo.snapshot dss
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasource ds ON ds.snapshotId = dss.snapshotId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasourceProperty dsp ON dsp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datapointProperty dp ON dp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
    WHERE dss.snapshotTime = (
        SELECT MAX(snapshotTime) FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot
    )
) t1
PIVOT (
    MAX(dsPropPropertyValue) FOR dsPropPropertyName IN ('+ @dsPropPropertyColumns +')
) AS pivot_table
PIVOT (
    MAX(dpPropertyValue) FOR dpPropertyName IN ('+ @dpPropertyColumns +')
) AS pivot_table2
ORDER BY id
'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Which correctly names the pivoted columns.