# Output multiple rows after joining and pivoting multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-sql

I have a couple of tables (in a SQL Server 2014 SP2 database) on which I have successfully pivoted (thanks to lptr in [Creating SQL pivot where duplicate column names exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70509741/creating-sql-pivot-where-duplicate-column-names-exist)). The next problem is that each datasource has one or more datapoints, but I am only getting one of the datapoints, per datasource.

The tables looks like this:

**dataSourceSnapshot**

```
|   snapshotId |     snapshotTime |
-----------------------------------
|            1 | 2021-12-01 07:00 |
|            2 | 2021-12-02 07:00 |
...
```

**datasource**

```
| snapshotId | dsRecordId | dsId | dsName |       dsTableDate |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |          1 |    1 |    cpu |  2021-12-01 07:00 |
|          1 |          2 |    2 |    mem |  2021-12-01 07:00 |
|          1 |          3 |    3 |  cache |  2021-12-01 07:00 |
|          2 |          4 |    1 |    cpu |  2021-12-01 07:00 |
|          2 |          5 |    2 |    mem |  2021-12-01 07:00 |
|          2 |          6 |    3 |  cache |  2021-12-01 07:00 |
...
```

**datasourceProperty**

This is a truncated list of datasource properties.

```
| dsRecordId | dsPropPropertyRecordId | dsPropPropertyName | dsPropPropertyValue |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |                      1 |                 id |                   1 |  
|          1 |                      2 |        description |           cpu stats |
|          1 |                      3 |               name |                 cpu |
|          1 |                      4 |    collectInterval |                 300 |
|          1 |                      5 |              group |                     |
|          1 |                      6 |         dataPoints |     System.Object[] |
|          2 |                      7 |                 id |                   2 |  
|          2 |                      8 |        description |        memory stats |
|          2 |                      9 |               name |                 mem |
|          2 |                     10 |    collectInterval |                 300 |
|          2 |                     11 |              group |                     |
|          2 |                     12 |         dataPoints |     System.Object[] |
|          3 |                     13 |                 id |                   3 |  
|          3 |                     14 |        description |                     |
|          3 |                     15 |               name |               cache |
|          3 |                     16 |    collectInterval |                 600 |
|          3 |                     17 |              group |                     |
|          3 |                     18 |         dataPoints |     System.Object[] |
...
```

**datapointProperty**

This is a truncated list of datapoint properties.

```
| dsRecordId | dpRecordId | dpPropertyName |    dpPropertyValue |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |          1 |             id |                  1 |  
|          1 |          2 |   datasourceId |                  1 |
|          1 |          3 |           name |           cpuState |
|          1 |          4 |    description |                    |
|          1 |          5 |      alertExpr |             != 0 0 |
|          1 |          6 |           type |                  2 |
|          1 |          7 |             id |                  2 |  
|          1 |          8 |   datasourceId |                  1 |
|          1 |          9 |           name |        freePercent |
|          1 |         10 |    description |    CPU utilization |
|          1 |         11 |      alertExpr |           >= 90 90 |
|          1 |         12 |           type |                  2 |
|          2 |         13 |             id |                  3 |
|          2 |         14 |   datasourceId |                  2 |
|          2 |         15 |           name |        freePercent |
|          2 |         16 |    description | Memory utilization |
|          2 |         17 |      alertExpr |           >= 90 90 |
|          2 |         18 |           type |                  2 |
|          3 |         19 |             id |                  4 |
|          3 |         20 |   datasourceId |                  3 |
|          3 |         21 |           name |              state |
|          3 |         22 |    description |                    |
|          3 |         23 |      alertExpr |            = 1 1 1 |
|          3 |         24 |           type |                  4 |
...
```

I am trying to get a row per datasource (but only the most recent instance of that datasource's entry) and per datapoint, which includes all of the datasource properties. Something like this:

```
| dsRecordId | id |    description |    name | collectInterval | group |      dataPoints | dp_id | dp_datasourceId |     dp_name |     dp_description | dp_alertExpr | dp_type |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |  1 |      cpu stats |     cpu |             300 |       | System.Object[] |     1 |               1 |    cpuState |                    |       != 0 0 |       2 |
|          1 |  1 |      cpu stats |     cpu |             300 |       | System.Object[] |     2 |               1 | freePercent |                    |     >= 90 90 |       2 |
|          2 |  2 |   memory stats |     mem |             300 |       | System.Object[] |     3 |               2 | freePercent | Memory utilization |     >= 90 90 |       2 |
|          3 |  3 |                |   cache |             600 |       | System.Object[] |     4 |               3 |       state |                    |      = 1 1 1 |       4 |
```

I have a bit of T-SQL that will pivot, but because datasources and datapoints both have id, name, and description properties, I have to exclude those properties in the pivot. This query:

```
DECLARE 
    @dsPropPropertyColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @dpPropertyColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

-- select the property names
--- properties in the datasourceProperty table
SELECT @dsPropPropertyColumns = (
    SELECT DISTINCT '[' + [dsPropPropertyName] + ']' + ','
    FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot dss
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasource ds ON ds.snapshotId = dss.snapshotId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasourceProperty dsp ON dsp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
    WHERE dss.snapshotTime = (
        SELECT MAX(snapshotTime) FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot
    )
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')

--- properties in the datapointProperty table
SELECT @dpPropertyColumns = (
    SELECT DISTINCT '[' + [dpPropertyName] + ']' + ','
    FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot dss
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasource ds ON ds.snapshotId = dss.snapshotId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datapointProperty dp ON dp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
    WHERE dss.snapshotTime = (
        SELECT MAX(snapshotTime) FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot
    )
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')

-- remove the trailing comma
SET @dsPropPropertyColumns = LEFT(@dsPropPropertyColumns, LEN(@dsPropPropertyColumns) - 1);
SET @dpPropertyColumns = LEFT(@dpPropertyColumns, LEN(@dpPropertyColumns) - 1);

-- construct dynamic SQL
SET @sql ='
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT dsp.dsRecordId, dsp.dsPropPropertyName, dsp.dsPropPropertyValue, CONCAT(''dp_'', dp.dpPropertyName) as dpPropertyName, dp.dpPropertyValue
    FROM dbo.snapshot dss
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasource ds ON ds.snapshotId = dss.snapshotId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datasourceProperty dsp ON dsp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.datapointProperty dp ON dp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
    WHERE dss.snapshotTime = (
        SELECT MAX(snapshotTime) FROM dbo.dataSourceSnapshot
    )
) t1
PIVOT (
    MAX(dsPropPropertyValue) FOR dsPropPropertyName IN ('+ @dsPropPropertyColumns +')
) AS pivot_table
PIVOT (
    MAX(dpPropertyValue) FOR dpPropertyName IN ('+ @dpPropertyColumns +')
) AS pivot_table2
ORDER BY id
'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Produces this output:

```
| dsRecordId | id |    description |    name | collectInterval | group |      dataPoints | dp_id | dp_datasourceId |     dp_name |     dp_description | dp_alertExpr | dp_type |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |  1 |      cpu stats |     cpu |             300 |       | System.Object[] |     1 |               1 |    cpuState |    CPU utilization |     >= 90 90 |       2 |
|          2 |  2 |   memory stats |     mem |             300 |       | System.Object[] |     3 |               2 | freePercent | Memory utilization |     >= 90 90 |       2 |
|          3 |  3 |                |   cache |             600 |       | System.Object[] |     4 |               3 |       state |                    |      = 1 1 1 |       4 |
```

This output shows one row for the "cpu" datasource (which has two datapoints). Confusingly, it also shows the datapoint (dp_) description and alertExpr values for the CPU's freePercent datapoint, with the "cpuState" dp_name.

In [Creating SQL pivot where duplicate column names exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70509741/creating-sql-pivot-where-duplicate-column-names-exist), it was suggested to use:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by dp.dsRecordId, dp.dpPropertyName order by dp.dpRecordId) as dpPropertyName
```

With this T-SQL:

```
SELECT dsp.dsRecordId, dsp.dsPropPropertyName, dsp.dsPropPropertyValue, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by dp.dsRecordId, dp.dpPropertyName order by dp.dpRecordId) as dpPropertyName, dp.dpPropertyValue
FROM logicmonitor.dataSourceSnapshot dss
LEFT OUTER JOIN logicmonitor.datasource ds ON ds.dataSourceSnapshotId = dss.dataSourceSnapshotId
LEFT OUTER JOIN logicmonitor.datasourceProperty dsp ON dsp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
LEFT OUTER JOIN logicmonitor.datapointProperty dp ON dp.dsRecordId = ds.dsRecordId
WHERE dss.dataSourceSnapshotTime = (
    SELECT MAX(dataSourceSnapshotTime) FROM logicmonitor.dataSourceSnapshot
)
```

I get get a table that looks like this:

```
| dsRecordId | dsPropPropertyName |    dsPropPropertyValue |    dpPropertyName | dpPropertyValue |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |                 id |                      1 |                 1 |                 |
|          1 |        description |              cpu stats |                 2 |                 |
|          1 |               name |                    cpu |                 3 |                 |
```

That does not look right, so I assume I am mis-using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `OVER()`.

The question is, how do I get a pivoted row per datapoint, joined to (or joined from?) the datasourceProperty and datasourceSnapshot tables

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? Side point: always quote column names using `QUOTENAME` not by manually adding `[]`

Comment: You should also construct the column names with the same prefix and should use them like that in the query. It should resolve to something like `PIVOT (  MAX(dpPropertyValue) FOR dpPropertyName IN ([dp_alertExpr],[dp_datasourceId],[dp_description],[dp_id],[dp_name],[dp_type])) ` . That being said, this doesn't solve your problem. It will always aggregate the unique values using max, so for cpu it will choose `max(dp_id)` = 2 and so on. I think your data needs to be better segregated before attempting to pivot.

Comment: ‘create view …’+ print(@sql)